# Visual Studio Extensibility (VSX) - Get the current branch name

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility, visual-studio-sdk

I am developing a Visual Studio extension (VS Package).

I am trying to get the Source Control branch name for a project/solution.

The only source control service available in the VS SDK is SVsSccManager but that doesn't provide any means of retrieving the source control branch name.

Also looked at DTE.SourceControl but alas, it doesn't give branch info.

I really don't want to develop my own Source Control plug-in to simply retrieve the branch name (this feels like total overkill).

Is there any way of retrieving the current branch name in source control for a solution/project?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: If doable, it's going to be specific to the type of SCC provider you're using. What sort of SCC provider are you currently using?

Comment: I'm using the out-of-the-box SCC provider.  In other words, I would like to use the base SCC provider for Visual Studio as I would prefer not to create my own (purely for retrieving the branch name)

Comment: It looks like overkill because you need to know what Scc provider what do you use and then use their informations to get what do you need. Scc providers are independently implemented and Visual Studio do not force them to implement some feauture. It s because there are real chance that exists Scc which has no branch logic for example. In Visual Studio is normally git and TFS providers which are implemented independently and do not share branch logic. So if you need to retrieve branch name you must get Scc provider and use their specific api to do this. Soo what do you use git or tfs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Visual Studio Extensibility (VSX) - Get the current branch name

If you are use git, there is already Visual Studio extension that displays your current Git branch on the title bar: [ShowMyGitBranch](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ThiagoSa.ShowMyGitBranch).

You can check the source code about this extension for more details:

https://github.com/thiagotts/show-my-git-branch

If you are use TFS, you can use API get branch for a project:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/89802f2e-f410-4a3a-a9c1-f776a3dd884e/api-get-branch-for-a-project?forum=tfsversioncontrol

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you!  This is perfect - what a clever solution. Essentially, it checks the .git folder, HEAD file for the branch name.

Comment: It supports VS until VS2015.
Can you add support for VS2019?