# When creating a Visual Studio extension, how can I write code that executes when the user checks out a branch of their code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to create an extension that remembers what files were open for each branch you were working on (I see one exists but it doesn't support 2019), but I've never created a Visual Studio extension before so I'm kind of lost - how would I detect when the user switches branches so I can close all the existing tabs and open the ones they had open the last time they worked on that branch?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Maybe [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52087358/visual-studio-extensibility-vsx-get-the-current-branch-name/52160935#52160935) can gets you some help.

Comment: Hmm, that looks interesting, but I'm looking for something that will fire an event or the equivalent when the branch is changed - I'd rather not have to have a background thread polling for branch changes!

Comment: My Task Canvas extension remembers what files were open for each task/branch. But it doesn't detect when the user switches branches, instead it switches branches itself when a user selects a different task.